# How to save generated kube config to .kube/config

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm using [rke](https://github.com/rancher/rke) to generate a Kubernetes cluster in a private cloud. It produces a `kube_config_cluster.yml` file. Is there a way to add this config to my `$HOME/.kube/config` file?

Without having the .kube/config set, when using `kubectl`, I have to pass the argument:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig kube_config_cluster.yml <command>
```

Or set the KUBECONFIG environment variable.

```
export KUBECONFIG=kube_config_cluster.yml
```

Comment: Look at the subcommands under kubectl config- they let you manipulate and switch between clusters and contexts (cluster + namespace + auth).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`kubectl config merge` command is [not yet available](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/46381). But you can achieve a config merge by running:

**Command format:**

```
KUBECONFIG=config1:config2 kubectl config view --flatten
```

**Example:**

Merge a config to `~/.kube/config` and write back to `~/.kube/config-new.yaml`.

#### Do not pipe directly to the config file! Otherwise, it will delete all your old content!

```
KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:/path/to/another/config.yml kubectl config view --flatten > ~/.kube/config-new.yaml
```

`cp ~/.kube/config-new.yaml ~/.kube/config`

Comment: This will make `~/.kube/config` unusable. Write to different file and then `mv` to `config`

Comment: UGH, I wish I read your comment before I tried this. It deleted my whole file

Answer (score 2):

If `kubectl` can read that as a valid config file, you can just use that as your kubeconfig. So `cp kube_config_cluster.yaml $HOME/.kube/config` should work fine. From there it'll read that config file by default and you won't have to specify it.

Answer (score -1):

I generally use the below commands to see and change context, not too cluttered and easy to fire

```
 
kubectl config current-context #show the current context in use
kubectl config use-context context-name-you-want-to-use
```